# Make posted links open in new window?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if it were feasible for links posted by users to open in new windows automatically instead of diverting traffic away from the site?

I know for me, when I visit a link someone has posted I hate to leave the question I was on, especially if it's rather engaging.

Comment: I to find this annoying sometimes, I often use right-click 'Open link in new tab' or similar for non-chrome browsers which is a simple enough workaround that it doesn't matter much to me. That said, not everyone is that tech-savvy and they may not know about the right click option, so it's officially a pickle. :)

Comment: @Dominic in most browsers you can use `Ctrl + Click` or click with `Mouse3`, in case you didn't already know. Much faster than right clicking!

Comment: Yeah, I use Ctrl (or CMD on my Mac) + Click most of the time. But, I tend to forget more often than not.

Comment: @JohnB That's even better, it still stands that many may not know that though. Maybe a little tool tip would benefit first time visitors. Is Mouse3 a 3 button mouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree with this because you should let the user choose what they want to do.

If all external links are to be opened in a new window by default, then the user has no say in the matter. Sometimes I *don't* want to open external links in a new window.  The way it is now, you can open the links however you want, I'm sure whatever user agent being used will have a keyboard or mouse shortcut to do so

I feel this way about any site, not just SE. In 99.99% of cases, the link behavior should not be dictated by the site. Power to the people!

Here's a good discussion on the matter over at UX: [**Opening website external links in new window — published usability tests**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/19892/31917)

And here is a discussion with arguments in favor of both ways over at MSO: [**make links posted by users open in a new window**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275/216955)

Comment: I can see your point.